# php DateTime sql problem

Tags: php, sql, datetime

well the problem is that when I use this

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($losDatos);$i++)
    {
        $fecha=new DateTime($losDatos[$i]['fechautc']);
        echo $losDatos[$i]['lat'];
        echo $losDatos[$i]['lon'];
    }
```

I always get the server date instead of my field name

```
$losDatos[$i]['fechautc']=2011-03-18 18:47:00.0
```

the field from the database is Datetime type from SQL , what could be wrong?

previously in the script I used

```
$initDate=$losDatos[0]['fechautc'];
```

and it worked well

Comment: What SQL? MSSQL? Postgres? MySQL? SQL Lite? Be specific, and include it in your tags.

Comment: The `.0` in `2011-03-18 18:47:00.0` I don't believe is recognized. Valid formats are listed here: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: erisco is correct, and it should be a string

Comment: previously in the script i used the same field with the same format and it worked well!

Comment: It would be useful if you post the dump of `$losDatos` to see what it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that `$losDatos[$i]['fechautc']` is `null` and so the `DateTime` is just showing the current time. Try dumping the array using `print_r` and see what's there.

Comment: as you said they are null but i dont know why , all the other data in $losDatos[$i] is as it should be

Comment: ok i found the trouble ,the field name was fechaUtc and not fechautc, i didnt know they were case sensitive